# Bind ListBox.SelectedItem to one object's property and ItemsSource to another List object (different Levels!)

Tags: wpf, list, xaml, data-binding

I have quite a simple question regarding WPF. I've searched around but didn't find the "the Answer" yet...

I would like to do a 2-level Data Binding. Simplified, I have a Person with some attributes, that also has N Addresses, each of some type and with some Zip Code (both selectable from a combo).

I retrieve the following Data from the server:

```
public List<AddressType> AddressTypeList; // catalogue of Address Types
public List<ZipCode> ZipCodeList; // catalogue of Zip Codes

public Person Person; // Person object
public List<Address> PersonAddressList; // Address List for that person (each has AddresType and ZipCode property)
```

Now, I'd like to bind this data to some controls. So, I put these properties into some custom class (say Data) and set the main user control's DataContext property to this object:

```
data = new Data();            

data.AddressTypeList = dao.GetAll<AddressType>();
data.ZipCodeList = dao.GetAll<ZipCode>();
data.Person = dao.GetPerson();
data.PersonAddressList = dao.GetPersonAddressList(Person);

this.DataContext = data; // this == some parent UserControl
```

Now, my XAML part for Address List looks something like this:

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxAddressList" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonAddressList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AddressTypeList}" SelectedItem="{Binding AddressType}"/>  
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Address}"/> <!-- this works! -->
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ZipCodeList}" SelectedItem="{Binding ZipCode}"/>  
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The Address property gets bound OK, but the AddressTypeList and ZipCodeList don't. It's kind of logical, since the PersonAddress (in PersonAddressList) doesn't have that property (they are on a different level!). I don't want to put the whole list of AddressTypes and ZipCodes into each address object, I would like to most painlessly bind it to "parent" or pass it to each Address List Item object somehow in XAML.

I think it's a common request to have a catalogue of some values in a combo (one list), but one of them is selected and that value is bound to another object's property. How would that be done properly?

Comment: I would create a ViewModel for PersonAddress item with necessary properties. Or you can try "{Binding Path=(DataContext.AddressTypeList), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}", but I'm not sure about this solution, so I won't send is as an answer.

Comment: I've already run into both of these possible solutions. I didn't like the first one, because I would manually have to set and then carry around all possible AddressTypes (and also ZipCodes etc.) in each of the Person's addresses... The second option (FindAncestor) seems kind of heavy (a lot of Reflection in the background I guess). I was searching for an elegant solution but it seems that it doesn't exist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 2:** You could also try to set up your lists as static properties, that way you might be able to bind directly using something like:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Data.AddressTypeList}}"
```

---

**Edit:** Try using RelativeSource to get back to the original data, something like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.AddressTypeList}" SelectedValue="{Binding AddressType}"/>
```

---

Also: Bind `SelectedValue` to the property instead of `SelectedItem`.

e.g.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" SelectedValue="{Binding Occupation}">
                    <sys:String>Programmer</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>GUI Designer</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Coffee Getter</sys:String>
                </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Doesn't quite answer my question... I have to bind "Data" to some parent UC that shows basic Person's data - name etc. (ItemsControl is one of its children components). But, the ComboBox's ItemsSource is supposed to be bound "back" to that parent component's DataContext, SelectedItem/Value binds OK (I have overriden the Equals method)!

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that at first, updated my answer, hopefully that is what you're looking for. Edit: Just saw you know about the Ancestor-approach already, i'd suggest you redesign your data-structure if you don't like that...

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of :).

Comment: This type of access I wasn't aware of, but it works and it also seems quite "lightweight". Marking as answer, now I have to review the situation and pick the aproach that suits me best. Thanks for your effort.